# receiving data from ajax to php doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Why I can't send data from my form to phps cript?

my js file:

```
var newMessage = {
                'name':    nameInput.val(),
                'email':   emailInput.val(),
                'message': msgInput.val()
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'contact.php',
                data: JSON.stringify(newMessage)
            }).done(function(res){
                console.log(res);
            }).fail(function(err){
                //console.log(err);
            });
```

and my php file:

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    json_decode($data);
    $name = json_decode($_POST['name']);
    echo ($name);
```

Comment: second line try this `$data = json_decode($_POST['data']); $name = $data->name;`

Comment: unfortunatelly ajax response is empty

Comment: try to debug by doing something like `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: var_dump give me `array(1) {
  ["{"name":"vgfgfd","email":"gdfdgf@dsasd","message":"dasdsa"}"]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

Comment: I recommend you use xdebug, make it break in the first line and inspect your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `JSON.stringify` on your object in javascript. JQuery will handle converting the data over for you. Just pass in the object to the data key like:

```
var newMessage = {
            'name':    nameInput.val(),
            'email':   emailInput.val(),
            'message': msgInput.val()
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'contact.php',
            data: newMessage
        }).done(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }).fail(function(err){
            //console.log(err);
        });
```

The way you are doing it, you are sending over the raw payload data in json format when it is expected in a format like a query string. JQuery will convert it for you to the correct format. Or if you really wanted to send raw json data like that (no benefit here), then you can use something like `$rawData = file_get_contents('php://input');` to read the raw input data which you could then `json_decode($rawData);`.